# POST multiple checkbox value tornado

Tags: python, forms, post, checkbox, tornado

I am messing around with a tornado web app with which I need a bit of help.  I have multiple checkboxes with the same name and I would like to POST the values of the selected one.

```
<input id=DB_BASED_ID name="activity" value=DB_BASED_ID type="checkbox"/>
<input id=DB_BASED_ID name="activity" value=DB_BASED_ID type="checkbox"/>
<input id=DB_BASED_ID name="activity" value=DB_BASED_ID type="checkbox"/>
<input id=DB_BASED_ID name="activity" value=DB_BASED_ID type="checkbox"/>
```

I can get the values of each with javascript pre-POST but am having troubles getting this list on the python (tornado) side.  i only get the highest selected value.

on the python side it looks like:

...

```
def post(self):
    email = self.get_argument("email")
    activity = self.get_argument("activity")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to let multiple tags have the same *name* attribute, but the *`id`* attributes **must** be unique -- here, they're not (unless each of those occurrences of the identical `DB_BASED_ID` is somehow meant to be replaced with a *different* value?  But then why not show the things *actually* distinct, as they do appear in the real HTML?!), making this invalid HTML and subject to all sorts of problems.

Once this problem is fixed, in those handler methods, `self.request.arguments['activity']` (if that string key is present in said directory) will be a list of non-empty values for all inputs named `'activity'` (if any).

Comment: thank you so much.  each id is different.  my goal is to get a list of activities that someone in which a person is interested.  i was hoping to pass an array of "checked" items back to the database. so the actual html would look more like 

<input id="1" name="activity" value="1" type="checkbox"/>Hiking
<input id="2" name="activity" value="2" type="checkbox"/>Biking
<input id="3" name="activity" value="3" type="checkbox"/>Camping
<input id="4" name="activity" value="4" type="checkbox"/>Fishing

i only care about the numeric value since that corresponds to the pk of the corresponding activity

Comment: @swash, then the code I give in the 2nd pararaph will work, except that you need to do your own filtering and conversion to integers, since the results will always be strings.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished with a loop for dynamic presentation & collection.  Hypothetically, if you provide a list to check from in the GET method, it can be displayed like so in HTML:

```
<p><h3>Select Applicable Characteristics:</h3></p>
{% for c in chars %}
    <p><h4><input type="checkbox" name="{{ c }}" value="{{ c }}"/> {{ c }}</h4></p>
{% end %}
```

The POST method can iterate that list, collect for each and create a list input.  It's slightly more technical but I could not make the aforementioned solution work.

```
# Characteristics loop
chars = [x.split('_')[1] for x in bs.attr.keys('chr_*')]
checked_chars = []
for c in chars:
    checked = self.get_argument(c, None)
    if checked is not None:
        checked_chars.append(checked)
```

This combines Tornado's templating (jinja2) feature with some html for a simple interface.  Doable & quick, admittedly not the best production solution.  Hope this helps!