# How to get POST form data that have dynamic IDs?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, tornado

I have checkboxes inside a form. These checkboxes are a list of persons dynamically created since this list depends on who is logged in. Like, for a supervisor view, it will only list your subordinates.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something but the docs and other answers in SO are all saying that you have to have the id of the input in order to retrieve the form data but in my case, I used the person's ID in the list to come up with the name of the checkbox element. So my checkbox names are like `input-{{person_id}}`

Now in the post method, I'm not sure how to retrieve the checkboxes in the form. Tried using `self.__dict__` but I can't seem to find anything that I can use

[link1](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=RequestHandler#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_query_argument) - this specifies the name

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640859/post-multiple-checkbox-value-tornado) - this also says that the ID should be pre-determined

[link3](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=RequestHandler#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_query_argument) - docs also say that if the parameter is not included, an empty list would returned

Maybe there is a workaround where I just get all the elements in the form and make them seen in tornado? Using javascript maybe?

Comment: Not `id`, but the `name` attribute is required for retrieving form input's value. The `id` is never sent to the server and it's just for doing browser side stuff.

Comment: oh shoot, wrong info. I'll correct it. but still, I'm not sure how I can access all the ticked checkbox since I won't know what their names will be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm mistaken, it seems that if you use the same name for a checkbox element for all the dynamic checkboxes you create, then when you submit it to the tornado web handler, it will get the values of all those checkboxes that have that name.

the values are retrieved by using the get_arguments

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you mean?

HTML

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="Name1" checked>
  <label for="box1">Name 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="Name2">
  <label for="box2">Name 2</label>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("form input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('name'))
})
```

Output

```
"Name1"
"Name2"
```

Comment: tnx for your reply. my problem is that I can't get to access the ticked checkboxes on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `request.body_arguments` attribute; it's **dict** which maps arguments names to lists of values (to support multiple values for individual names).

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        for key, value in self.request.body_arguments.items():
            print(f"key {key} has value: {value}")
        ...
```

There are also `arguments` (holds both query and body args) and `query_arguments` (holds only query args) attributes; you can check the docs [here](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.arguments).